# How to jump to the first component's reference in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have two components called `Category` and `Item`:

```
/src
  - Category.tsx
  - Item.tsx
```

```js
import Item from "./Item";

const Category = (...) => (
  <>
    <Item />
  </>
);

export default React.memo(Category);
```

```js
const Item = (...) => <>...</>;

export default React.memo(Item);
```

As you can see, `Item` is being referenced just once (inside `Component`). So far, so good.

Now, I want from the `Item.tsx` file to directly jump into `Category.tsx` since I'm actually using this component once. But when I do so, VSCode opens a window saying I have 4 references (which it basically right):

1. const **Item** = ...
2. ... React.memo(**item**)
3. import **Item** from ...
4. <**Item** />

I was wondering if there's a way I can tell VSCode that I'm only interested in the 4th reference () so it can navigate me directly to this reference instead of opening the references window.